# putting average of column in footer, I can get the sum

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am able to sum an entire column and put the total in a column, but what if i want to get the average of all the numbers in the column?

```
    Dim paxaverage As Decimal = 0.0
        Function GetAverage(ByVal hope As Decimal) As Decimal
'this is where i am stuck
            paxaverage += hope / saods.Tables("salesasoftable")Rows.Count
            Return hope
        End Function
        Function Getaverage1() As Decimal
            Return paxaverage
        End Function
```

Asp side

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remaining PAX">
<ItemTemplate>
 <%#GetAverage(Decimal.Parse(Eval("RemainingPax").ToString())).ToString("N0")%>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<%#GetAverage1().ToString("N0")%>
</FooterTemplate>
    <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/displaying-summary-information-in-the-gridview-s-footer-cs) discusses a couple of approaches to this problem and gives you some sample code.  The one I've used in the past is to have a couple of private fields in the Page code-behind: one for the count and one for the sum. You can then increment these in the GridView's `RowDataBound` event when the row in question is a data row. When it is a footer row, you compute the average and display it in the right cell.

Comment: I actually got it, it was simple since my other columns were being computed by functions i just had the next column be function1/function2